# why is index false still searchable?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm puzzled by this

i have the following field defined in elastic

```
  "Email": {
    "type": "text",
    "boost": 0,
    "index": false,
    "analyzer": "standard"
  }
```

however when i search the records i'm getting records that only match on this field with the following highlight statement included

```
  "highlight": {
    "properties.Email": [
      "<mark>someone</mark>@somewhere.com"
    ]
  }
```

my understanding is that index:false is supposed to prevent that field from being searchable and that if its not searchable is shouldn't be included in the highlighted results

so is my understanding wrong or is there something wrong else wrong

EDIT: futher information reqested
the full mapping was reqested
orginal data is GeoJson

```
 "index_5b17968c789cdb21dea23bfa": {
    "mappings": {
      "client_record": {
        "properties": {
          "geometry": {
            "type": "geo_shape"
          },
          "job_id": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "boost": 0,
            "index": false
          },
          "properties": {
            "properties": {
              "Address": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Address_1": {
                "type": "text",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false,
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "Address_2": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Address_3": {
                "type": "text",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false,
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "Company": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 18
              },
              "County": {
                "type": "text",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false,
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "Email": {
                "type": "text",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false,
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "Ref_ID": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 27
              },
              "FirstName": {
                "type": "text",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false,
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "Job_Title": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Land_Description": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Registry_Title": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 18
              },
              "LastName": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Middlename": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Mobile": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Name": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 18
              },
              "Notes": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Record_Type": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Parish_Council": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Item_Name": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Postcode": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Preferred_Contact_Method": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Prior_Notification": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Tel": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Tenure": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Title": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Town": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              },
              "Work_Tel": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "boost": 0,
                "index": false
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "boost": 0,
            "index": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the search logic was requested so adding it here

i'm using the PHP interface but this is the search query

where
$q is the string provided by the user
$index ares the indexes being searched

```
[
    'index' => $index ,
    'ignore_unavailable'=>true,
    'size' => 20,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    "bool" => [
                        "should" => [
                            [
                                "match_phrase" => [
                                    "_all" => [
                                        "query" => $q,
                                        "boost" => 8
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                "match" => [
                                    "_all" => [
                                        "query" => $q,
                                        "operator"=> "and",
                                        "boost" => 2
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                "match" => [
                                    "_all" => [
                                        "query" => $q,
                                        "boost" => 1
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                "wildcard" => [
                                    "_all" => [
                                        "wildcard" => '*' . $q . '*',
                                        "boost" => 0.5
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]

                ]
            ]
        ],
        'highlight' => [
            'pre_tags' => ['<mark>'],
            'post_tags' => ['</mark>'],
            'fields' => [
                '*' => [
                    'require_field_match' => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: `"index": false` should prevent Elastic from indexing that field. What does the rest of your mapping look like? What does your query look like with the highlighting?

Comment: Could you post your search query, to see what you have tried?

Comment: @Tim Added the rest of the mapping

Comment: @cinhtau added and now i feel like a complete idiot for forgetting i'd added 'require_field_match' => false to the highlight, which is the answer i altered the default behaviour which is why its not following default behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Elasticsearch Internals topic. In short, the information remains in `_source`, as it is used by highlight.

A little bit more detail. Citing [Mapping Parameters - index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html):

> The index option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts `true` or `false` and defaults to `true`. Fields that are not indexed are not queryable.

This is all to it. The value doesn't go into the [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) of Apache Lucene, so a query is pointless. However, the field remains in `_source` and is still usable for aggregations. An example for aggregation: Let's assume you want to know, how many docs exists to specific mail addresses.

If you don't want to use it for aggregations, you can add the `"enabled": false` [mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html).

[Highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-request-highlighting.html) is another concept.

> If the field is not stored (the mapping does not set `store` to `true`), the actual `_source` is loaded and the relevant field is extracted from `_source`.

In brief it access the `_source` field. The information remains in `_source` for the mapping parameters `index` and `enabled`. This is in most of the cases mandatory. If you disable source, you can't

- update the doc (fixing data)
- reindex the index (fixing data)
- upgrade to a newer index version

Comment: so you are saying that the Highlighting is a red herring and that what is highlighted isn't the areas of the index that were used to match this record in the search?

Comment: @MikeT I am not familiar with the term red herring, but I guess the key is to distinguish between searching and highlighting field values. I think elastic could improve the documentation. In the Elastic Engineer Training you learn about Elasticsearch Internals. HTH

Comment: A red herring is something that misleads or distracts from a relevant or important issue